# In Neo4j, is there any way to restrict nodes and relation types in path while using Java API?

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases, path-finding, neo4j-java-api

I have source node and destination node I want to put restriction on nodes and relation types in the path. I am using [Neo4j Java API](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/).

Consider following toy example,

We have three person nodes A, B & C.

**Source Node: A** & **Destination Node: B**. There are many other kind of paths may exists between them. I want to restrict paths to specific format like-

`(person) -[worksAt]-> (company) -[CompetitorOf]-> (company) <-[worksAt]- (person)`

This can be very easily achieved from cypher query, but I want to know is there any way we can do it using Java API.

[image]

**NOTE:**

1. Kindly do not suggest putting restriction on path length, that
   doesn't solve the problem. I want to restrict the node and relation
   types in path.
2. Example mentioned above is toy example. Graph I am trying to work is more complex and there are many possible paths not feasible to traverse and validate individual paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the [Neo4j java documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/) carefully and experimenting with the code I got following solution working-

To filter path explored by [`PathFinder`](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphalgo/PathFinder.html) create a custom [`PathExpander`](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/PathExpander.html) using [`PathExpanderBuilder`](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/PathExpanderBuilder.html).

```
PathExpanderBuilder pathExpanderBuilder = PathExpanderBuilder.empty();

pathExpanderBuilder.add(RelationshipType.withName("worksat"), Direction.OUTGOING);
pathExpanderBuilder.add(RelationshipType.withName("competitorof"), Direction.BOTH);
pathExpanderBuilder.add(RelationshipType.withName("worksat"), Direction.INCOMING);

PathExpander<Object> pathExpander pathExpander = pathExpanderBuilder.build();
```

Once you create a custom `PathExpander` you can use it to create appropriate `PathFinder` which will filter traversal by the `PathFinder`.

```
PathFinder<Path> allPathFinder = GraphAlgoFactory.allSimplePaths(this.pathExpander, 4);


Iterable<Path> allPaths = allPathFinder.findAllPaths(sourceNode, targetNode);
```

In our example `sourceNode` would be Node 'A' and `targetNode` would be Node 'B'.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really clear from your question what you're actually trying to compute. Do you have A and B and want to find if their companies are competitors? Do you have C and want to find who among their friends work at competing companies?

Anyway, if you're using the traversal API (you're talking about paths), you can write a custom [`PathExpander`](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.0/javadocs/index.html?org/neo4j/graphdb/PathExpander.html) which will use the [last relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.0/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Path.html#lastRelationship--) in the [`Path`](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.0/javadocs/index.html?org/neo4j/graphdb/Path.html) to determine the next type of relationship to traverse.

If you're just traversing the relationships manually, I don't really see the problem: just call [`Node.getRelationships(RelationshipType, Direction)`](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.0/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html#getRelationships-org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType-org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction-) with the proper parameters at each step.

Contrary to what you do in Cypher, you don't *declare* the pattern you're looking for in the path, you just compute the path to follow the wanted pattern.